# How do I have excel remove all rows with a certain formatting (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm trying to remove all rows that have the "name" column formatted with any 4 letters followed by the letter X

For example, if the name column had "ABCDX" I would like to delete the row. Not sure if VBA would be the best approach, or if there is another solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `if len(range("a" & rownum).value)=5 and right(range("a" & rownum).value,1)="X" then`

Comment: If upgrading to Office 2016 is an option for you, Power Query is built into that. You could pass your table into that system and manipulate your dataset in any way you can imagine (without VBA or formulas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without VBA, apply a `Text Filter` to the name column with criteria `????X` and then delete the visible rows. After deleting rows, clear the filter applied and you won't find any name with four letters followed by a `X`.

Answer (score 0):

Also without VBA, run a FIND ALL operation (CTRL-f > Find All) for "????X" then click CTRL-a in the find dialog to select all of the instances. Then on in the HOME menu, select DELETE > DELETE CELL ROWS. This will automatically remove all of the gaps as well.

Comment: CTRL with the "-" key is a shortcut to pull up the delete dialog...select Entire Row while all of ABCDX cells are selected.

Comment: and it's advised to pre-select the entire name column before running the find all operation...otherwise you may find values in other columns (and those rows will get inadvertently deleted as well).